# NGINX Reverse-Proxy Forbidden 403

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, cloudflare

I have the problem, that I have a express-js webserver and im hosting it with an nginx reverse proxy. I want a basic authentication with an .htpasswd file. I copied an configuration of my other subdomain, where i have it actually and it works there, but at this subdomain it wont work. After I login i get Error 403. The configs are absolutely identical, except of the path's.
Here is my config. I have replaced the path and Domain-Names.

```
upstream subdomain-domain-com{
        server 127.0.0.1:3003;
}
server {
        include cloudflare.domain.com.ssl;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;


        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
        location ~ ^/(assets/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.$
        root /srv/www/subdomain.domain.com/www/public/;
        access_log off;
        expires 24h;
        }
         location / {
                auth_basic "Kennwort eingeben";
                auth_basic_user_file /srv/www/subdomain.domain.com/.htpasswd;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header x-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }


}
```

Edit: chmod = 777 and user = root
Edit²: If I put the chown of the .htpasswd to nginx:nginx nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

I just read the logs and it said it could not find the .htpasswd. I changed the path and now its working..